# How to deploy a REST (Jersey) serivce on Tomcat in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, rest, tomcat, jersey, web-deployment

I was looking for a way to deploy a Jersey webservice on Tomcat using eclipse, but I didn't find simple or clear examples, and I would like to know the steps to follow or an example to make the job done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't done so already, download a tomcat installation and use it to set up a server runtime in eclipse:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Then open your server configuration by double clicking on its name in the Servers tab.
Under 'Modules' click 'Add Web Module...' to add your project and specify the path for deployment (if you don't see your project in list of modules or if the button is disabled, make sure your project has the 'Dynamic Web Module' facet, you can check by right-clicking on your project > Properties > Project Facets)
[image]
Under 'Overview' you can further set up your tomcat environment (by setting up port values, timeouts etc..)

[image]